# FutureProvider does not return data to UI

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm new using Riverpod and its providers. I have 2 almost identical futureProviders but one of them does not return data to UI even though API returns data.

Here is UI part

```
class ProductDetailSimilarProductsWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ProductDetailSimilarProductsWidget(this.product, {super.key});

  final ProductDetailModel product;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    var value = ref.watch(getSimilarProductsFutureProvider([product.Id, product.KategoriId]));
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: value.when(
        data: (data) {
          print("data length:${data.length}");
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: AppTheme.mediumPadding, right: AppTheme.mediumPadding),
                child: ProductGridContainerWidget(product: data[index]),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        error: (err, trace) {
          return Text(err.toString());
        },
        loading: () => AppTheme.spinkit,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is futureProvider object

```
final getSimilarProductsFutureProvider = FutureProvider.family<List<Products>, List<dynamic>>((ref, value) async {
  var result = await ProductDetailData().getSimilarProducts(productId: value[0], categoryId: value[1]);
  print("result: ${result.length}");
  return result;
});
```

Finally, the method does API call

```
    var service = ApiService();
    var sharedPreferencesManager = SharedPreferencesManager();
    await sharedPreferencesManager.init();
    var langId = await sharedPreferencesManager.getLanguageId();
    var countryId = await sharedPreferencesManager.getCountryId();
    var result =
        await service.getRequest(subUrl: "${ApiRoutes.getSimilarProducts}?productId=$productId&langId=$langId&countryId=$countryId&categoryId=$categoryId");
    List<Products> products = [];
    var elements = json.decode(result.body);
    await Future.forEach(elements, (element) => products.add(Products.fromMap(element as Map<String, dynamic>)));
    return products;
```

Inside provider object, result.length variable prints 10 and it is expected. But inside the UI part, **widget stucks on loading part** and **does not print data.length variable**.

Is there something wrong in my codes? Also API works fine and successfully returns data.

Comment: Did you try change to using `FutureProvider.autoDispose.family` instead of `FutureProvider.family` because you are returning list. https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is probably using the list as an argument for `.family`.

> Ideally, the parameter should either be a primitive (bool/int/double/String), a constant (providers), or an immutable object that overrides == and hashCode.

Try using [Records](https://dart.dev/language/records) or create an immutable object with the two required fields.